# Erro ao efetuar teste de conexão no Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-4, conexão

Eu sou novo em programação em ASP.NET, e estou tentando a conexão do Visual Studio 2013 Express com o SQL serve 2012 Express e não estou tendo resultado.

Eu fiz os seguintes procedimentos;

procedimento 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

procedimento 2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

procedimento 3.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a senha está correta, fiz um teste de conexão e não teve sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu não sei se o drive de conexão está correto, veja ;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu baixei o SQL Express 2012 desse link

http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=29062

e somente baixei o arquivo que tinha 1.3 Gigas.

Comment: Quando coloca os dados de login e senha tem o botao testconnection... no caso se o botao OK funcionou... foi criado com sucesso... o visual studio é amigao do sqlserver... entao nem precisa se preocupar com as referencias(drive)... se nao existir alguma ele vai falar pra vc... ou vc pode procurar pelo add reference que vai estar la!

Comment: Tente utilizar pelo windows authentication... SQLExpress apenas deixa local... entao utilize o ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: se eu for conectar como windows authentication eu não conseguir enxergar as bases de dados que criei no sql serve 2012 Express.

Comment: Defina "não teve sucesso". Existe mais de uma dúzia de formas pelas quais uma conexão pode falhar. Se você nos indicar qual foi a que ocorreu com você, teremos mais facilidade para ajudar ;)

Comment: A imagem mais importante (do erro) está em branco. Pode corrigir o link da imagem?

Comment: eu conseguir corrigir, criei uma string de conexão e funcinou . mesmo assim quero agradecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resposta do autor da pesgunta:

> eu conseguir corrigir, criei uma string de conexão e funcinou . mesmo assim quero agradecer. – wladyband

Comment: nossa mano, uma postagem de 2014 rsrs, hoje estou trabalhando com Java, mas valeu.